# assistance with amending an excel array formula?

Tags: excel

I have inherited a production log which contains a worksheet with multiple columns and about 8k of rows each month.  I am looking to build a statistics tab, and work out for a particular time frame how many unique dates are logged against an agent.

Worksheet "log":

```
Column A contains agents initials
Column E contains case completion date
```

Worksheet "statistics":

```
C2 contains a dropdown of agent initials
C5 and D5 contain dates to generate a date range
```

I have written the following array which identifies the unique dates for the date period.

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Log!E:E>=CC1,IF(Log!E:E<=DD1,IF(Log!E:E<>"",MATCH(Log!E:E,Log!E:E,0)))),ROW(Log!E:E)-ROW(Log!E3)+1),1))`

I just can't tie in the agents initials in Log!A:A and it matches C2.

Comment: I would suggest that this is taken out of an excel file and put into a database, this is what they are for, you can then perform these types of tasks much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an array formula, avoid using whole column references.  Otherwise you'll find it very slow.  Or Excel will run out of resources.  Try...

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Log!$A$2:$A$100=C2,IF(Log!$E$2:$E$100>=CC1,IF(Log!$E$2:$E$100<=DD1,IF(Log!$E$2:$E$100<>"",MATCH(Log!$E$2:$E$100,Log!$E$2:$E$100,0))))),ROW(Log!$E$2:$E$100)-ROW(Log!$E$2)+1),1))
```

...confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.  Although, I think there's no need to test Column E for blank/empty cells, since you're already testing it for a date range...

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Log!$A$2:$A$100=C2,IF(Log!$E$2:$E$100>=CC1,IF(Log!$E$2:$E$100<=DD1,MATCH(Log!$E$2:$E$100,Log!$E$2:$E$100,0)))),ROW(Log!$E$2:$E$100)-ROW(Log!$E$2)+1),1))
```

...also confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.  In either case, adjust the ranges, accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Domenic that worked.  I appreciate your comment about column references as I have crashed excel twice today as it ran out of resources.

If I wanted to reverse that formula to work out for a particular time frame how many unique dates are logged however i want to ignore the agent in C2.  would it be

=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Log!$A$2:$A$300<>C2,IF(Log!$E$2:$E$300>=C5,IF(Log!$E$2:$E$300<=D5,MATCH(Log!$E$2:$E$300,Log!$E$2:$E$300,0)))),ROW(Log!$E$2:$E$300)-ROW(Log!$E$2)+1),1))